# How can I display an image from a file server with HTML

Tags: html, image, server, display

I have a website that displays a lot of messages and images, usually through normal HTML  tags.  We now have a file server where we would like it to be our one stop place to retrieve files and images.
  I can create links that allow me to download files from the server but I can't find anyway of displaying the images on the web pages.

To clarify a bit more, our web page is running through a server we'll call SERVER1, and we used to just retreive our files from that server.  Now we are still running the website through SERVER1 but want to display images from a different server named FILESERVER.

links like
http://SERVER1/imagedocs/image.jpg used to work but

http://FILESERVER/imagedocs/image.jpg doesn't work

while

file://FILESERVER/imagedocs/image.jpg does work but I believe this is because I have a local connection to the server and will not work if I apply it to the website.

Any clues on what I should be looking for as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

the `file:\\` means it's a local file opened by your browser.
There might be various reasons why you can't access stuff that are currently on your server. I will take as granted that the file is actually on your second server, and you havent made a typo ( you can still double check it though, double check the filepath too (( maybe it was ROOT/dir/image.jpg and now it's ROOT/image.jpg)) ). Do you know if your 2nd server is blocking connections perhaps ? Have you succesfully connected to it? i'd suggest you to ping your server adress to see if you got a response, if it does ping, we going to need more infos about the way your server have been set up.